# Is there a way to easily access the emoticons I use most in iMessage?

Tags: ipad, macos, imac, messages, emoji

I often use the same emoticons in Messages and would like to quickly access the same set both in my iPhone, iPad, MacBook and iMac. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: could you explain what is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

When you add the Emoji-keyboard on iOS (`Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards > Add New Keyboard > Emoji`), it automatically collects the recently used emoticons on the first tab at the bottom (the clock icon).

The same goes for Messages.app on OS X; when you open the Emoji-selection from the smiley-face in the input box, it shows the recent ones first.

However, on OS X you can select which emoticons are shown in the favourites, a feature currently missing on iOS. You can do this by opening the `Characters viewer` from the top right corner of the Emoji-popup and selecting `Add to Favorites` for the emoticons you like.

Also, there is no way to sync these usages and selections between devices, at least currently and using stock OS's.